# Limiting UITextField to a certain character range

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uitextviewdelegate

Can someone help me figure out an easy way to limit the UITextField range, so that the entered number is between 14 and 70, and if the number is greater or less that the one inside the range, the textfield would just clear itself? I have already limited the length of the entered text to be not more than 2 characters like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range      replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *newString = [ageField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range     withString:string];
return !([newString length] > 2);
```

The only thing left is to implement this behavior. Anyone?

Comment: Use Regular Expressions.

Comment: If you could downvote comments, I would definately do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

```
  NSInteger v = [newString integerValue];
 if (v < 14 || v > 72) {
// Do whatever you do when the string value is invalid
// BUT ALSO ADD:
textView.text = @"";
}
```

Instead of returning try:

```
   if (newString.length != 2) {
  // do what you want!
return;
} else {
// PUT YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: it's fine now, but when i type in a value, say, 10, it just deletes the first number, leaving "0" in the textfield, making it possible to enter 0 :(

Comment: The main problem turns out to be in the code `return !([newString length] > 2);` it DOES restrict numbers which are more than 2 digits but it ALLOWS entering a one-digit number. Is it possible to change somehow, then? :(

Comment: Now it doesn't allow me to input any numbers at all :(

Comment: Made a stupid careless mistake check updated for comment answer

Comment: neither `return !([newString length] == 2)` nor `return ([newString length] == 2)` nothing at all works :( I'm doomed due to my stubbornness :(

Comment: haha, so whats the problem
what you need to do is make sure there is 2 digits right....

Try what I updated

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll try to think about my implementation :)